# Sending variables from code behind to web page via callback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, callback, devexpress

I have to make a callback method to update my web page without making a postback request. There is a problem that I need to recognize what type of message it has to display.

In web page I have the following code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="ASPxCallbackPanel2" runat="server" Width="200px" ClientInstanceName="ASPxCallbackPanel2" autopostback="false" OnCallback="ASPxCallbackPanel2_Callback">
            <PanelCollection>
                <dx:PanelContent>

 <% if(ViewState["message_ok"].Equals(1)){ %> 


   <div class="notification-summary-container">
       <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel3" runat="server" Text="ASPxLabel"></dx:ASPxLabel>


       </div>
(...)
 <% if(ViewState["message_ok"].Equals(2)){ %> 
<div class="notification-summary-error">
(...)

But there is a problem when I call the `JavaScript` function to perform the callback like:

function call(s, e)
{
   ASPxCallbackPanel2.PerformCallback();
   e.processOnServer = false;
}

My ViewState is not updated in the callback method

protected void ASPxCallbackPanel2_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
{
   ASPxLabel3.Text = "blabla";
   ViewState["message_ok"]=1;
}
```

I know that it is caused by updating view state after post back but callback method doesn't make postback.  I would like to know if there is a possibility to send variables to web page code via callback, or maybe set appropriate message via `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, Callback cannot access out of it scope so try use `Session` instead of `ViewState`. It is the easiest way.

Or try the second way,
Add `Label1` inside `callbackPanel tag` and set `ClientSideVisiable to false` then set value to this `Label1.Text = "OK"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JSProperties:

```
protected void ASPxCallbackPanel2_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
{
   ASPxCallbackPanel panel = sender as ASPxCallbackPanel;
   panel.JSProperies.Clear();
   // JSProperties have to begin with a 'cp'
   panel.JSProperties.Add("cpIsOk", true);
}
```

On client side you could handle the EndCallback:

```
ASPxCallbackPanel_EndCallback(s, e){ 
   if(s.cpIsOk != null && s.cpIsOk == true){
      // Do your stuff here...
      s.cpIsOk = null;
   }
}
```